# Can a Pokemon remember a move they previously had, but are not normally able to learn?

Tags: pokemon-scarlet-violet

Right now, you can get a Pikachu with Fly via a [gift](https://www.serebii.net/events/dex/025.shtml#2022). Obviously, Pikachu is not normally able to learn Fly. If I accidentally tell Pikachu to forget Fly, will he be able to remember that move? Or do I need to be very careful about what moves he learns?

Comment: I’m not sure how it is for the Gen9 games, but I can say for previous generations event/gift exclusive moves couldn’t be re-learned through a move tutor (happened to a friend of mine where the daycare overwrite V-Create on his Victini)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In Gen IX, it seems Pokemon can re-learn any move they learned from a TM or an event. As demonstrated in the screenshot (Move was forgotten beforehand.)

However, moves that were learned by a pre-evolution (but not available to a later evolution) and egg moves appear NOT to be re-learnable. For example, I found a Sylveon that knew Yawn, but I could not re-learn Yawn when I forgot it. Yawn is an egg move for Sylveon. Apparently, it's the same for moves only learnable by pre-evolved forms of Pokemon as well.

An example of an event move being re-learnable (This applies to TMs as well):

[image: Screenshot of a special event Pikachu able to remember Fly]

Comment: Does that option persist when traded away?

Comment: This answer is not quite correct, if you delete Spore off of Breloom, it cannot relearn it, since Spore is unique to Shroomish.

Comment: @thomas-markov Thanks for your comment, I noticed this also applies to egg moves when I caught a wild Sylveon that knew Yawn. I updated my answer.

Comment: @PaulO. I was sorely disappointed when I had to build another competitive Breloom. But now I have a solid raid Breloom - Choice Band with Bullet Seed, Mach Punch, Aerial Ace, and Rock Tomb; good coverage and hits like a truck.